# Excel If Cell Dropdown is selected, then price in Cell 2 Dropdown is decreased by a certain amount

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a dropdown of percentages. The list is cells A1:A3 and the dropdown is cell B5.

[image: Price Dropdown List]

[image: City Dropdown List]

I want the selection in B5 to change if the user selects a city in cell B6

Example:

- User selects 0% in B5
- User selects Chicago (-10%) in B6

Output: -10% (0%-10%=-10%)

**What I have tried**: I wrote the following in cell B5 **=IF($B$5="Chicago","0%-10%")**

I will have different price decreases for each city. I am unsure how to use this formula when there is a dropdown.

Comment: If you have a list of cities and a list of rebates, then a [`VLOOLKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) should do what you want

Comment: I know next to nothing about dropdowns, but there are two low-hanging problems with what you posted so far: What I have tried: I wrote the following in cell B5 =IF($B$5="Chicago","0%-10%"). First, that's a circular reference as your `B5` formula is referencing `B5` when it shoul dbe `B6`. Second, your [value_if_true] is surrounded by quotes, meaning that if the "Chicago" condition is satisfied you're outputting the text string "0%-10%"

Comment: It seems that, as far as logic goes, what you want is to put a formula in **`C5`** that runs `=IF($B$6="Chicago",$B$5-10)` where both numbers in `B5` and `C5` are set to percentage format, and you're using **`C5`** as your final output. And of course as @cybernetic.nomad has noted, once you get past 3-4 different city/rate pairs, you want to have a rate table and use a `VLOOKUP` instead of hard coding a lengthy nested `IF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the price dropdown out of what would be the output. The user will select the price increase. Then the user will select the city which will have a decrease. I then add those percentages together.

I still used an IF statement for if the cell contains a word then this cell shows a certain value. Ex, RSCCH was selected, so the output is -10% + 20% from the price dropdown to give a final output of 10%.

=IF(B8="RSCCH",-10%,0)

[image: excel example]